# Python | Как убрать буквы из списка?

Tags: python, list

мне нужно как то убрать буквы из списка и чтобы остались только цифры как в примере:
`list([1,2,'a','b']) == [1,2]`

Comment: И в чем проблема/вопрос?

Comment: я не знаю как это сделать

Comment: Придётся взять учебник и почитать основы работы со списками. Сейчас тут нет даже попытки решить задачу.

Comment: Я пытался. Создавал новый список, потом проходился по старому и проверял если элемент == int то добавить его в новый список

Comment: на будущее: имеет смысл код попытки включать в текст вопроса и указывать на место, которое не работает.

Comment: ==int  это совсем не то, что вы думаете

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно использовать функцию `isinstance`:

```py
print(list(filter(lambda x: isinstance(x, int), [1,2,'a','b'])))
```

Answer (score 2):

Через `list comprehension`

```py
print([i for i in [1,2,'a','b'] if isinstance(i, int)])
```